# Place Button at top right corner of an element with position:relative

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote this script:

```
var HTML_BT = '<a class="helper" href="#"><i class="icon-wrench"></i></a>';

// Append button
$("my_selector").live('mouseenter', function(){
    var 
        bt = $(this).find('a.helper'),
        pos = $(this).position();

    // Check if the button exists and creates it
    if (bt.length==0){
        bt = $(HTML_BT);
        bt.css({
            position:'absolute',

            // Calculates coordinates
            top:pos.top + 15 + 'px', 
            left:pos.left + $(this).width() - 15 + 'px'

            // .. Some other css like border, bg, color and so on.
        });
        $(this).append(bt);
    }

    // Show the button
    bt.show();

}).live('mouseleave', function(){
    var 
        bt = $(this).find('a.helper');

    // Show the button if exists
    if (bt.length!=0){
        bt.hide();
    }
});
```

The script shows or appends a link at top/right corner, when the mouse cursor goes on a specific item.

It works fine, but I have some troubles calculating the top and right coordinates on elements placed inside containers that has specified the css position as relative, because the link coordinates are (rightly) calculated as relative of his container.

```
.carousel-inner{
    position:relative;
}
```

Here I did a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ucfKm/

Someone knows how to test if I have to use absolute / relative coordinates or how to get the right left position?

Thanks a lot, Davide.

Comment: I'd say you probably want `position: fixed;` that way it will be at the top left of the browser window rather than the top left of the element it's in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calculating the left position to put it on the right and the top position just remember that an absolutely positioned element inside a relatively positioned element will have its 0,0 at the top left corner of the parent, so:

```
top:15 + 'px', 
right:15 + 'px',
```

Will position your a element at 15 px from the top of the parent and 15px from the right of the parent.

Fiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/ucfKm/5/

EDIT: Also, note that because you dont have to calculate the position in this case, you can assign the css directly to the class on your css file, and avoid unnecessary javascript logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!
Unfortunately I can't do that, because I have both, relative and absolute containers.

I can wrap my element with a relative container and do that, but I don't know if it is a good idea...

Comment: Its not a problem, you can add position:relative to your .carousel-inner without it affecting anything (so long as you dont add top/right/bottom/left attributes), then position:absolute; top:15px; right:15px; to the .helper inside it. Check the version 5 of the fiddle in the answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

`position: relative;` does not position the element relative to the parent. It positions the element relative to that element's original position.

If you want the element to be positioned 15px from the top and right of the parent (as long as the parent has `position:` set on itself with a value of either `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`), use:

```
.carousel-inner{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}
```

If you want the element to be positioned 15px from the top and right of the entire page, use:

```
.carousel-inner{
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}
```

In either case, you have no need of doing javascript position calculations.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that..
 
In my page I could have multiple elements, fixed, relative or absolute and what I do is to distribute a javascript that enables this link as a button on the top right of each element. 

I really don't know the real markup of the page. The only thing I know is that the web site is written using Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery. This is the reason why i calculate coordinates with javascript..

Comment: Having multiple elements is where `position: absolute;` shines. As long as there is some sort of container element to position against, then you can use that as the basis for your positioning. If need be, you can check the position of the parent and (if it is not set), set it to `position: relative;` without impacting how the parent element is rendered (since you won't be setting a top/left/right/bottom value for the parent).

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, finally is what I did ;)